# Throw temporary instead of local variable - why?

Tags: c++

The code in question is this:

```
struct something_bad_happened_exception : std::exception {};

void foo() {
    something_bad_happened_exception e;
    throw e;
}
```

clang gives a warning that reads:

> Throw expression should throw anonymous temporary values instead
>   [cert-err09-cpp]

which means `foo()` should be changed to:

```
void foo() {
    throw something_bad_happened_exception();
}
```

Why is it better to throw a temporary instead of a local variable?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/misc-throw-by-value-catch-by-reference.html

Comment: @StoryTeller I've seen that, but there is no explanation, just the details of what triggers the warning.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in your case, it seems like a silly warning, a true false positive.

Comment: So the purpose of the warning would be to warn about throwing things like instance variables? If yes, this could be the answer...

Comment: It could, but I can only speculate.

Comment: Maybe something to do with copy/move elision?

Comment: I don't see the point of this warning either. `e` will be copied, why would it be a problem? I don't see any cases where this could cause some problem. If `e` was a reference, then object slicing could occur (that's a problem, a warning would be well-founded in this case).

Comment: There is a difference If `e`'s copy-constructor could throw  (e.g. if `e` has a `std::string` member variable)

Answer (score 9):

According to the cpp reference on a [throw expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression (this may call the move constructor for rvalue expression, and the copy/move may be subject to copy elision)

Thus, your code if perfectly fine, but a copy constructor will be called, which may be undesirable in terms of efficiency. Still, [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) may occur if (emphasis mine)

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, **but not required** to omit the copy
>
> [omissis]
>
> In a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and whose scope does not extend past the innermost try-block (if there is a try-block).

As an example, consider the following code

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct something_bad_happened_exception : std::exception {
  something_bad_happened_exception(const something_bad_happened_exception& r) {
     std::cout << "A copy has occoured!" << std::endl;
  }
  something_bad_happened_exception() { }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "First throw" << std::endl;
  try {
    const something_bad_happened_exception e;
    throw e;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "Caught exception" << std::endl;
    }
  std::cout << "Second throw" << std::endl;
  try {
    throw something_bad_happened_exception();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "Caught exception" << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling the code with `gcc 8.2.1` and `clang 6.0`, with option `-O3` the output is

```
First throw
A copy has occoured!
Caught exception
Second throw
Caught exception
```

The first `throw` corresponds to your example. Even if a copy of `e` *could* be omitted, neither `gcc` nor `clang` implement copy elision.

The second `throw` has an anonymous temporary, and no copy occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The code doesn't conform to the convention of "[throw only anonymous temporaries](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/misc-throw-by-value-catch-by-reference.html)" (note the option `CheckThrowTemporaries`), which is what the style checker inspects.

That convention, and this inspection are overly strict as far "throw by value" convention is concerned - in that regard the example program is conforming. A truly non conforming example would be throwing a pointer to an object.